# 'in appreciation' vs. 'appreciatively'

Tags: adverbs, semantics, synonyms

Is using the adverbial prepositional phrase *in appreciation* in place of the adverb *appreciatively* convey exactly the same meaning?

I'm attempting to avoid the use of the adverb "appreciatively" in the following sentence:

> I whistled in appreciation. "Wow."

Am I missing the spirit of the thing, or is this acceptable (i.e. not likely to lead to the bad habit of showing instead of telling)? If not, what would be a good way to indicate that somebody is whistling to show that they appreciate something?

Note: I am not indicating a "wolf-whistle" in this sentence.

Comment: This looks like Off Topic writing advice to me. What's wrong with *"I whistled appreciatively"* anyway? And if you seriously think your readers would assume a wolf-whistle if you just wrote *"Wow! I whistled"*, you should probably change your readership.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: My readership right now is the members of this Stack Exchange site, and I wanted to avoid receiving colloqualisms of "wolf-whistle." Is this particular question off-topic or is writing advice in general off topic? And as for adverbs--well, Stephen King once said "the road to hell is paved with adverbs."

Comment: If you want writing advice, go to [writers](http://writers.stackexchange.com/). And if you want to write without adverbs, go ahead. But don't assume that'll make you as successful as Stephen Kimng.

Comment: Ok, thanks, didn't know that site existed. As for writing without adverbs--I make no assumptions save that King is rich and I'm not, so he must be doing *something* right.

Comment: In any case, it's not so much about the literary aspect as it is about the semantic difference in the sentence, if any, between using the preposition and the adverb here. That's about ELU.

Comment: Yes, you are right about "missing the spirit of the thing".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about writing advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer your preferred alternative, for the reason that 'in appreciation' connotes the **reason** for the whistle, 'appreciatively' the **manner**.

Comment: I think that's a totally spurious distinction in this context. You could just as well *wolf-whistle* "appreciatively" or "in appreciation".

Comment: I agree that the denotations of OP's alternatives are the same, but maintain that I pick up a different emphasis. The adverb focuses attention on the whistling, the PP on the noun it contains.

Comment: Well, if that's how you perceive it, I can hardly say you *don't*, can I? Taking a structurally similar example, I would draw a distinction between *"He ate in haste"* and *"He ate hastily"*. But it's not that one denotes the reason and the other the manner - it's just that the former (in this specific case) is more dated/formal. Whatever - if you see a distinction in OP's case, all I can say is the effort of choosing the "right" one for the right context would normally be entirely wasted, since few if any readers would pick up on it.

Comment: Let's take another structurally similar example. _He retorted in anger_ can obviously be read as giving the reason for the reaction whereas _he retorted angrily_ just qualifies the manner of retort.